# Angular JS model is not updated immediately using Bootstrap popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ngmodel

I am using ng-repeat for iterating through a list of objects, and for each item in the list there are child objects which are edited in a Bootstrap modal popup. I am unable to use the Angular modal service as it conflicts with the Bootstrap CSS already in use on the page. Angular modals would let me take values back from the modal popup on modal close, but I am unable to use it due to existing code.

To work around this problem, I am passing the child object to the function that opens the modal popup.  In this function, I assign this passed object to an Angular model/jQuery Object (say "x") (either way I tried, it gives same result) so that I can update this new object x with the changes done in the modal popup.

I believe that these variables as copied and points to the same object, when I update one, it should update the other one and so my original Angular model should be updated as well. But, to my surprise, the original model is not updating until I open the modal popup again. When I open the modal popup again, it does not update variable "x" but merely is updated with the ng-model I use on page.

To debug this further, I printed my ng-model on page and it is not updated till modal popup is opened again. To contrast this further if I alert length of this ng-model, it is updated (shows the changes I made in modal popup) but the ng-model object on page does not show new values.

I understand this is more of a theory and less code but I am not sure what part of my code would help find the problem. Kindly let me know and I will try sanitize my code and share.

Update:
While further digging, it looks like the model is updated but it did not reflect on page. So if for example on page I have condition that if no child objects, show Add button (edit otherwise), it does not change from add to edit button when I open modal first time and add values to child objects. When I open modal popup again, it changes link from add to edit even if I close modal popup without changes. So it is a problem with screen refreshing as such (my model updates reflecting on screen) instead of actual model update.

Comment: You should use the bootstrap ui modal service.  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal.  It doesn't conflict with the Bootstrap CSS -- on the contrary, it requires it.

Comment: Well, that could be a case, but when I tried using bootstrap UI modal, it conflicted with my existing bootstrap CSS and did not work well. I am working on some existing code so unable to tweak existing CSS much and change modal service.

Even though I use Bootstrap modal, the model update should work and update page.. Isn't it? My question is about model update not reflecting on screen, rather than changing modal service.

This plunker created by someone else has somewhat resemblance to my situation. In this, 4th option popup does not reflect changes when made until you open popup again.

Comment: I was just wondering if we have any feedback on this problem?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  You're saying the model does update immediately, it just doesn't reflect on the view.  If your problem is solved, you should post your solution as an answer.